# TypeError: Cannot read property 'express-validator#contexts' of undefined

Tags: javascript, express, postman, express-validator

I am trying to validate some data using express-validator middleware v6.10.1 but it turns out some unusal error when I am testing it with postman.

My code:

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')

router.post('/', [
  check('name', 'Required Field!').not().isEmpty(),
  check('email', 'Required Field!').not().isEmpty(),
  check('email', 'Not Valid Email Format!').isEmail(),
  check('password', 'Required Field!').not().isEmpty(),
  check('password', 'Password Must Contain At Least 10 Characters!').isLength({ min: 10 }),
  check('type', 'Required Field!').not().isEmpty()
], (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult()

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
  }
  res.send('users route...')
})
```

The error that shows in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'express-validator#contexts' of undefined
```

Anyone can explain for me this error and help me to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://express-validator.github.io/docs), `validationResult` function requires an argument:

`const errors = validationResult(req)`